# How can one measure time for a large block of code except when stopped at a breakpoint?

Tags: c++, debugging, time, breakpoints, measure

I am working on a C++ game / simulation / graphics application on Windows.
  *(edit start)* If it matters, I am using Visual Studio 2013. *(edit end)*

**Setup:** I am measuring the time from one frame to the next using QueryPerformanceCounter().

**Steps to Reproduce:**
Stop at a breakpoint for some debugging.

**Current Undesired Result:** When application resumes execution, the next time QueryPerformanceCounter() is called, it will return a time value that includes all of the time was spent paused at the debugger.  This results in a frame time length that is abnormally large.

**Desired Result:** QueryPerformanceCounter() will return a time value that does not include however much time I spent paused at a breakpoint for debugging.

How can I achieve the desired result?
 1. Is there a different function that I should use instead of QueryPerformanceCounter?
 2. Is there some setting in an IDE (i.e. Visual Studio) that can be changed?
 
 3. Is there some special way to use QueryPerformanceCounter or other
    time function?
 4. etc.

**Reference Notes:** There is a somewhat similar question listed here, but it was not helpful for me to identify a solution. [Tracking Time Spent in Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155682/tracking-time-spent-in-debugger)

Comment: Have you access to C++11? You could use the utilities in <chrono>, but I am unsure whether it will work correctly if you use a breakpoint.

Comment: take a measurement before and after the breakpoint line. subtract it from the overall time.

Comment: I would just have a "debug mode" where the code deals with "long frames" (say more than 0.1s or 0.5s) by "thinking it is a normal value" (e.g. 0.0167s [1/60s]). That way, your debugged code will behave reasonably similar to actual application running in realtime. Unfortunately, debugging timing dependent code will ALWAYS be nasty and complex. (I'd enable/disable this based on debug/release build)

Comment: @RichardHodges Thanks for the suggestion. It's usable but it's unfortunately not a very portable solution. i.e. Every time I create or delete a breakpoint I have to remember to modify the code around it.

Comment: What Visual Studio version is in use?  In VS 2015, the time for each execution line is shown.  The units are only to the millisecond though.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understand what you're trying to do.

- Duration measuring in debug mode is useless. The differences between Debug and Release are dramatic. The ratio between different execution times of different functions is not necessarily the same in Debug and Release.
- If you need to fix bottlenecks, use a profiler (in VC go to Debug | Profiler).

If you still want to measure the time in Debug mode, here's an idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>

struct duration
{
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point _s;

  duration() : _s( std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() )
  {
    // nop
  }

  auto ms() 
  { 
    return std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>( std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - _s ).count(); 
  }
};

struct breakpoint
{
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point _s;
  duration& _d;

  breakpoint( duration& a_d ) : _s( std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() ), _d( a_d )
  { 
    __asm {int 3} 
  }

  ~breakpoint() 
  { 
    _d._s += std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - _s;
  }
};

int main()
{
  duration d;

  Sleep( 1000 );
  std::cout << d.ms() << std::endl;

  breakpoint { d };

  Sleep( 1000 );
  std::cout << d.ms() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and for the code sample.  It's taking the idea that @RichardHodges mentioned and implementing it in a way that is more user friendly.
To answer one of your questions, I'm not trying to do performance profiling or fix bottlenecks.

Comment: I guarantee that is not accurate to the ms. Please describe your method for verifying its accuracy.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Of course it is not very accurate. However, the error should be fairly constant so you can compare durations.

Comment: The former part of your answer is great. The latter suggestion would be quite misleading in any real code that is expected to run 30-120 times a second, not to mention being quite worthless anyway, as explained in the former part of your answer.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz How would you run it n times/second when you have a breakpoint in the middle?

Comment: @ZDF Again, the question is why are you concerned with time at all when you are breaking in debug mode with no optimizations, and expecting anything that resembles how it will behave in production? What information are you after and why? If you want to test what occurs during a frame then test it independently from wall time, by providing time deterministicly. The conclusion is going to be wrong using this nonsensical timer code. It simply isn't useful in any scenario.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz _"... the question is..."_ this is a question OP must answer. You probably understood the question better than me.

Answer (score 2):

Use a commercial profiling tool. Measuring how long it took to execute a function or method is exactly what they are made for.

Also, why would you care how long something took while you were debugging? Are you planning on releasing to your customers in debug mode, and crawling through line by line remotely while they play? If you want to examine frame time, examine it in release with optimizations turned on.