# C++ timing while debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, time

I have a little problem in my project:
I use C++ chrono library for the time stuff in my program. But when I reach a breakpoint while debugging the chrono clock continue running and when I continue the programm there are crazy values in the stuff that works with the timer together.

Now my Question:
Is there a library or way to have a "debugg-time" clock to prevent the called problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Use dependency injection along with unit testing with deterministic results. An excellent example: https://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters

Comment: @Chris Or floobargle the zongle with the pooper.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I wouldn't recommend floorbargling the zongle. The pooper is entirely unpredictable.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I agree with Neil. How is this relevant?

Comment: @captain You'd have to actually read the article. I can't type the whole thing out in 500 characters. Remove the non-deterministic timer from debugging efforts, and test your code with deterministic results in a nutshell.

Comment: Consuming plenty of fibre is one way to get a deterministic pooper.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370915/how-can-one-measure-time-for-a-large-block-of-code-except-when-stopped-at-a-brea/36377547#36377547) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic tool that stops time while you are examining code in debug mode.

You work around the specific problem where the timers skew your results. I can't give you specific recommendations, because you haven't supplied the specifics on how your timer is effecting your results, much less a usable description of what you are trying to debug through at all.

I often follow the advise given in the following article:
https://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters

To remove non-deterministic factors from unit tests, then use unit tests as my driver to debug my code. Whether or not that would solve your problem depends on the details of your problem.

In a nuttshell, separate what you are debugging from the timer.